# Mail merging with text boxes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

So I have a simple, WORKING, mail merger script here.

I would like to introduce text boxes in the 'doctemplate' google doc file. Which take in output elements from the 'createMailMerge' function, and input them into the text boxes.

I have no idea how to do this.

Btw this is not my code, link to youtube video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNPPEB64QbI&t=1616s

```js
function myFunction() {
  var doctemplateId = "1ndllkTur5tZgLUw5dO-UTh5VVOVWEN8I5JkZeJEDKEU";
  var docFinalId = "1xQlmVtLDBI7SmcmlF9axmnWbnNNMAk6tOJTuYqslCsE";
  var wsId = "16F4ubVJ8Hlj5a3euvL1U8vxPbCV7FWl4w-4y3GmRVSo";

  var doctemplate = DocumentApp.openById(doctemplateId);
  var docFinal = DocumentApp.openById(docFinalId);
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(wsId).getSheetByName("data1");

  var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 7).getValues();
  var templateParagraphs = doctemplate.getBody().getParagraphs();

  docFinal.getBody().clear();
  data.forEach(function(r){
    createMailMerge(r[0], r[1], r[2],r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], templateParagraphs, docFinal);    
  });  
}

function createMailMerge(first, last, city, state,street, apt, zip, templateParagraphs, docFinal) {
  templateParagraphs.forEach(function(p) {
    docFinal.getBody().appendParagraph(
      p
      .copy()
      .replaceText("{first}", first)
      .replaceText("{last}", last)
      .replaceText("{city}", city)
      .replaceText("{state}", state)
      .replaceText("{street}", street)
      .replaceText("{apt}", apt)
      .replaceText("{zip}", zip)
      );
  });
}
```

Comment: I am very limited in my understanding of coding.

Comment: You should really attempt some code, stackoverflow isn't a place for people to code for you and even an attempt at something will go a long way. It looks like this isn't possible though as the docs API is quite new and lacks a lot of functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this can't be done - Google Apps Script doesn't have methods which allow you to be able to create TextBoxes in a Document file.*

#### Explanation:

In Google Docs, Text boxes are actually `InlineDrawing` objects which contain text - in the Graphical Interface you can create these by following `Insert > Drawing > + New` and then clicking the `Text box` icon in the toolbar. As you can see in the Apps Script Documentation for Google Docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-drawing), there is no method to create, only one to copy existing Drawing objects.

#### Feature Request:

On the plus side, Google knows about this! As you can see on their Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36754517) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764836), a Feature Request to Create and Modify Drawings has already been made. You can give these Feature Requests a star (☆) in the top left to let Google know more people wish for this request.

#### References:

- [Class InlineDrawing of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-drawing)
- [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

  - [Add ability to create and modify drawings](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36754517)
  - [Google Apps Script support for Google Drawing](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764836)